# Azure Mobile Service and Azure Web App authentication

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

I get two different SID for the same user when the user is logging in through a Azure Web App (ASP.NET MVC) and Xamarin.iOS app

**Setup**

Azure WebApp ASP.NET 5 with API Controllers

Xamarin iOS App with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Client SDK Azure B2C AAD

**User on Web**

I get the ObjectIdentifier value that is the AAD SID:

```
var userClaim = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
```

**User on Mobile**

I get only a Nameidentifier value and no ObjectIdentifier

```
ClaimsPrincipal mobileUser = this.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
var mobileUserClaim = mobileUser.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier");
```

The SID is completely different, the SID for the user authenticate from Mobile get SID:xxxx while from Web gets xxx

I know if I setup one Azure Mobile App and one Azure Web App the SID is the same when authenticating. But I dont want to manage two sites for the size (small) of my App. The purpose of the App is to have a Simple Web App to perform some actions and the same actions on the Phone, from the Phone I use the Azure Mobile Service SDK and InvokeAPIAsync to use the API controller in the Web App.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I want to clarify the situation.
You are observing two SIDs:

1) From AAD, by logging into AAD via web browser.

2) From Azure App Service (Web App and Mobile App), likely from using LoginAsync from our client.  This method would invoke the server-directed login flow.

This is by design.  MobileServiceClient gets App Service tokens, and authenticates with your Mobile App with that token.  You can exchange the auth token you get from Azure App Service for the AAD SID by making a GET to the .auth/me endpoint.

After your client is authenticated with App Service and AAD, you can get more information about the AAD user (or whatever identity provider) by calling yoursite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me, and parsing the response for the claim you want:

({"typ" : "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").

Another strategy would be to use ADAL (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/) from your client app to login with AAD, and then use the AAD access token to get a Mobile App token using the appropriate LoginAsync overload:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/master/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.iOS/Extensions/MobileServiceClientExtensions.cs#L55

The parameters you add should be in format {"access_token":"[AAD access_token value]"}

Brett Samblanet's wiki on the .NET Server about User IDs should help understand what is going on:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Understanding-User-Ids

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I have tested your example with using the LoginAsync overload with Token, but I used bearer instead or access_token. Ill test this tonight. Thanks

Comment: Another question: If I use ADAL from Client (iOS app), can I use the AAD AccessToken retrieved to authenticate the user against my WebApp API? I tried this. where authResult.AccessToken is the AAD Access token through ADAL. But I was never able to authenticate against my WebApp API, got unauthorised. Is the parameter wrong, instead of Bearer, should it maybe access_token ? Ill give it a try tonight. 

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);

Comment: @JCB Sorry for the delay.  No, your AAD Access Token cannot be used to authenticate against WebApp.  You need to exchange it for an AppService token.  Specifically, look again at the LoginAsync() overload I mentioned at the end of my post.  The result of that will be an App Service token.

Comment: Hi Aziel, sorry for my delay as well. Have not had time to try this, but I did now. 

When I use the LoginAsync overload, I get the PopOver View to login to AAD again.

Dictionary<string, string> msgDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
msgDic.Add("access_token", authResult.AccessToken);
await mobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(this, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, msgDic);

If this had successfully logged in and I had gotten the App Service Token, what value should be on the Auth, header with this token against the Azure Web App, Bearer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work:

```
string authority = "https://login.windows.net/[TentantId].onmicrosoft.com/";
            string resourceId = "[myApiClientId]";
            string clientId = "[clientId]";
            string redirectUri = "https://[URL]/.auth/login/done";

            AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            AuthenticationResult ar = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientId,
                new Uri(redirectUri), new PlatformParameters(this));
            JObject payload = new JObject();
            payload["access_token"] = ar.AccessToken;

            string authHeader = ar.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "[API URL Route]");
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authHeader);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```