# Azure Mobile App Service API authenticated user identity

Tags: .net, azure, authentication, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I have a Xamarin Forms app that uses AD B2C to authenticate and then makes calls to APIs in an Azure Mobile App Service. The app service is created with .NET and returns user-specific data from a database. The problem is that I am getting a different user ID in the TableController service than I am in a custom API Controller service. Both services are set up with the Authorize attribute.

The first call is to a Mobile App Service TableController api which determines the user ID with this code:

((ClaimsPrincipal)User).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value.

The client's primary steps are as follows:
1. Get token from AD B2C: PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync()
2. Login with the token to the mobile app service: MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync (pass token in payload)
3. Call Mobile App Service TableController API: IMobileServiceTable.ToEnumerableAsync()

This seems fine. In the table controller the value of the user ID is retrieved from the NameIdentifier claim. The value at this point is always in the format: "sid:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" (the x's are hex characters).

The client then makes a call to another service which is an ApiController (with a MobileAppController attribute). That service uses the same code as above to get the user ID (from the NameIdentifier claim). But the user ID that is retrieved is different than what was retrieved by the TableController.

The client code is basically as follows:

```
    authResult = await B2CPublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync();
    string url = [endpoint for the custom api]
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    message.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.IdToken);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);
    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The call to the custom API endpoint is successful and it is successfully authorized, but the user ID is different. The user ID is of the format: 
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx where x is a hex character.

Obviously I need one user to have the same user ID every time it calls any app server service.

Comment: Looks like those are two different methods. There is an answer to a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36258052/731115

Comment: @mikalai - thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for.